# Fusion Chart: how to adjust 'displayValue' Y-position

Tags: fusioncharts

Is there any way to adjust 'displayValue' (not the value) on a stacked bar chart? My JSON looks like this:

```
{
"chart": {
    "animation": 0,
    "canvasBgColor": "FFFFFF",
    "showBorder": 0,
    "borderColor": "FFFFFF",
    "bgColor": "FFFFFF",
    "yAxisValuesPadding": 5,
    "divLineColor": "DDDDDD",
    "showValues": "1",
    "showSum": "1",
    "numDivLines": "1",
    "yAxisMaxValue": "228",
    "adjustDiv": "0",
    "divLineAlpha": "100",
    "scrollColor": "FFFFFF",
    "showCanvasBorder": "1"
},
"categories": {
    "category": [
        {
            "label": "Sep 07 Sep 13"
        },
        {
            "label": "Sep 07 Sep 13"
        }
    ]
},
"dataset": [
    {
        "color": "4DB6C1",
        "seriesName": "tomatoes",
        "data": [
            {
                "value": "6",
                "displayValue": "01 Oct",
                "toolText": "6 tomatoes"
            },
            {
                "value": "50",
                "displayValue": "02 Oct",
                "toolText": "50 tomatoes"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "color": "AFBCD6",
        "seriesName": "potatoes",
        "data": [
            {
                "value": "6",
                "displayValue": "01 Oct",
                "toolText": "6 potatoes"
            },
            {
                "value": "38",
                "displayValue": "02 Oct",
                "toolText": "38 potatoes"
            }
        ]
    }
],
"styles": {...}
```

}

So I have two stacked columns, series names: tomatoes and potatoes. And if I hide tomatoes and there is just 5 of potatoes per period, the displayed value = "02 Oct" is got cut as it's aligned based on the column height.

When generated the code looks like this:

```
<text x="664.5" y="182" text-anchor="middle" stroke="none" fill="#223a67" style="text-anchor: middle; font-family: Verdana; font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold;" font-family="Verdana" font-size="12px" font-weight="bold">
```

And what I need to do is to change 'dy' attribute for the tspan, so when the bar itself is small, the displayValue still could be visible.

Is there any chart fusion method to do that?

Comment: It seems you have pasted the DOM element of FusionCharts. It is hard to give you a solution this way. Please create a fiddle to render the Chart (maybe with dummy data) and tell us what changes you want.

Comment: Added JSON with the dummy data. Please review if you could help to fix the issue. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems that the values can not be placed outside the bars and there is no such attribute available for this chart.

Comment: :(  I see. Thanks, @pallabb. Could this be covered with annotations somehow?

Comment: With annotations you can draw anything anywhere on the chart. using either absolute coordinates or with the help of Macros. See the below link for details. You might need to read a bit to understand the Dynamic Macro concepts

http://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/advanced-chart-configurations/annotations/real-life-use-cases.html